# Calling an Apex method on an Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, method

I am trying to call an apex method on an apex trigger. But here i am receiving following error. Here is the code which i used.

Apex Class:

```
public class EmailExample {

    public void mailSending(){
        Contact con= new Contact();
        String mail1=con.email;
        String[] mail2= new String[]{mail1};  
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toadd= new String[]{'mail'}; 
        email.setToAddresses(mail2);
        Messaging.Email[] mail3 = new Messaging.Email[]{email};
        Messaging.sendEmail(mail3);
    }
}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger MailingContactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {
    EmailExample.mailSending();

}
```

Error which i am getting:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   EmailExample.mailSending()

could you please anyone clarify why i am getting above error.

Thanking you
KS Kumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your method should be **static**

```
public static void mailSending(){
//rest of your code
}
```

now you can call this method using

```
EmailExample.mailSending();
```

---

if you don't want to use static method then you could do like below example

```
public class EmailExample {

    public void mailSending(){
        //rest of your code 
    }
}
```

and in trigger

```
trigger MailingContactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {
    EmailExample emailHandler = new EmailExample();
    emailHandler.mailSending();

}
```

first initialize and then call your class method

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the method has been defined as an instance method, meaning you cannot access it directly, you first must instantiate the class.

For example, you would have to do the following to call the method:

```
new EmailExample().mailSending();
```

Now if you don't want this you could alternatively define the method as static. Static methods do not require you to instantiate the class and can be accessed directly.

To define a method as static add the modifier "static" to the method signature:

```
public static void mailSending(){
  // your code
}
```

Bare in mind that you cannot access properties or methods which are not marked as static within your mailSending method.

Hope this helps!